# how to get image file from absolute path in php

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have absolute path of my uploaded image file and i want to get image file which i uploaded in my folder. So how can i get image file and how i can upload image.So i can perform image operation like watermark and rotate. So i have to get image file in code igniter.

i tried but it is not working

```
$upld_file = 'my absolute path';
$real_path = realpath($upld_file);
$img = base64_encode($real_path);
```

and i send $img parameter to upload image

I am getting "you did not select a file to upload"

> C:\wamp64\www\codeigniter_project\assets/images/1551892667300.jpeg

This is my absolute path of my image

Thank You.

Comment: You have not actually loaded the file into PHP anywhere. All you are doing is fiddling with a string containing a path and filename

Comment: actually my question is how can i get file from path. and i am able to get file so i can re_upload

Comment: See [`file_get_contents()` in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: file_get_contents return string in my project but how can i send string for upload image in php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the absolute path of the image if you are storing the images inside a `assets` in the root of your project directory, You can access the image like this

```
echo base_url('assets/images/1551892667300.jpeg');
```

**NOTE :** *you need to load the url helper first*

Comment: yes but how can i get file from path ? how can i re_upload in php?

Comment: What do you mean by re_upload?

Comment: actually it is stored in my images folder but i want to perform image operation for update image file so i need to get my image file in php

Comment: If you want perform image operations then just provide that path to any method you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

```
//define image path
$filename="C:/wamp64/www/codeigniter_project/assets/images/1551892667300.jpeg";

// Load the image
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);

//and save it on your server...
imagejpeg($rotate, "savedestinationpath.jpg");
```

Comment: i tried but it returns "pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Answer (score 0):

That should be the file input name. eg: If your file browse input name is `myFileInput` then it should be `$this->upload->do_upload('myFileInput')`

Also make sure that you have set attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for your form.

One nice example is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_file_uploading.htm)

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('what i pass in this') how can i get image field name

Comment: That should be the file input name. eg: If your file browse input name is `myFileInput` then it should be `$this->upload->do_upload('myFileInput')`

Comment: Also make sure that you have set attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`for your form.

Comment: @UrvishPatel I have updated the answer based on your input here.